# Different methods of calling system commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, exec

On searching for how to call system commands, I found there to be many methods in Python. How does one choose between different methods of calling system commands:

Method 1:

```
os.system('ls -l *.py')
```

Method 2:

```
os.popen("ls -l").read()
```

Method 3:

```
subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", "*.py"]);
```

Method 4:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("ls -l *.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
```

Method 5:

```
from shell_command import shell_call
shell_call("ls -l *.py")
```

What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of each? Which ones are especially recommended for python3 versus python2. Are there any methods which will work in both versions?

Answer (score 1):

> **Short answer: go with subprocess module**

Any flavor from `subprocess` should be used depending on what you need (input, output, pipes), but `os.system` and `os.popen` are definetly to be [replaced](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) and shouldn't be used anymore.

`subprocess.check_output` is a wrapper around `subprocess.Popen`as the other sibling commands `subprocess.call` and `check_call` and only returns  the output of the command, but doesn't manage any communication.

`subprocess.Popen` is the base method and it used to do more sophisticated process communication like One-Way/Bidirectional and PIPE redirecting.

`shell_command` is a package that eases shell interaction and it is based on `subprocess.Popen`. If you are not doing a lot of system admin work, no need to use it.

**So, how do you choose which `subprocess` call you need?**

> **1) No need for shell interaction, just Fire and Forget?**

`subprocess.call` is the direct replacement of `os.system` and `os.call`. You call it and don't care about the output. The command line arguments are passed as a `list of strings` or a single `string` (shell=True mode only), which free's you from the burden of escaping quotes or special characters.

**Example:**

```
subprocess.call(['ls', '-l'])
```

The return value is the exit code of the application itself, if you want to know if the external command crashed/succeed or any other exit command, you have to handle it yourself.

> **1a) You need automatic Error Handling**

If you want python to deal with the error handling, a convenient function `subprocess.check_call` is available, which is the same as `subprocess.call` but it raises a `CalledProcessError` exception if the process returns any other error value than `0`.

```
try:
   subprocess.check_call(['false'])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    print 'Error:', err
```

> **2) Interested in the output of the external command?**

`subprocess.call` and `subprocess.check_call` are bound to the output of the parent's programm, so they cannot capture the output of the command. `subprocess.check_output` is the command that captures the output of the command.

Example:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'])
print output

total 941234
drwxr-xr-x    28 user  staff           1972 Dec   9 11:24 test.cpp
-rw-r--r--     1 user  staff            799 Jan   1 09:12 out
```

> **3) Communicate with your process?**

still writing...it's going to be about POPEN.. :)

Comment: Thanks for a very good explanation. Looking forward to remaining part. Also which of these methods are specific for python2 or python3?